# How do I type arbitrary unicode characters in xterm?

Tags: xterm, unicode

Moving away from using gnome-terminal and terminator since they are excruciatingly slow. (20-30 seconds to change focus to them for whatever reason)

xterm is nice and fast. However, I need to be able to type certain unicode characters in vim for documents I am working on. With gnome-terminal and terminator I could do ctrl+shift+u + hex code, however that does not work in xterm.

How do I type arbitrary unicode characters in xterm?

OS is Debian 8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

xterm doesn't implement a hexadecimal-input feature because all of the text editors which handle UTF-8 provide their own equivalents ([emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html), [vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2822) and [vile](http://invisible-island.net/vile/CHANGES.html#v9_5s), of course, even [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.0/faq.html#3.8)).  This could be useful in a shell script, but is not often mentioned.  The feature was first implemented in Windows, of course.

To enter multibyte (e.g., UTF-8) characters in xterm, you would use compose sequences.  As a special case, the <kbd>meta</kbd> key can be used as a sort of *shift* to get the 128-255 coverage of UTF-8, but aside from that, compose is what works.

gnome-terminal (more properly VTE), also implements compose, although there are some differences.

Further reading:

- [Using eight-bit-characters in X11.](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/X11/input8bit.html)
- [Compose key and xterm vs. UTF-8](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2010-March/213702.html)
- [how to insert unicode characters in xterm](https://superuser.com/questions/193344/how-to-insert-unicode-characters-in-xterm)
- [How to type special characters in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux)

Comment: Couldn't Ctrl+Shift+U or something like it be implemented through an input method? Not that I think character input via codepoint number is convenient, but I don't see why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Perhaps, but the ones I recall don't do it that way.  They are essentially extensions of the compose feature.

Answer (score 2):

As [Thomas Dickey explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280468), xterm has no built-in way to input characters by codepoint. (Presumably because that's pretty bad UX.)

[Vim does, though](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/mbyte.html#utf-8-typing): in insert mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then `u` then 4 hex digits (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then `U` then 8 hex digits). For a more convenient way to input characters, use [<kbd>Compose</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), [digraphs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraphs) (which are Vim's built-in compose facility), or an input method suited to the language you're writing in.